# Access columns of a table having the same prefix

Tags: matlab

I need to select all the columns of a MATLAB table whose name starts with `'data'`. The table is formatted as follows:

```
sub. | age | gender | ... | ... | data1 | data2 | data3 | ... | data4 | ... |
```

Is there a way to do so? Something like `selected_table = table.data*`

Comment: Hint: you can use ```YourTable.Properties.VariableNames``` to get your variable names and ```strncmp``` to compare to your prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% Generate test data
T = table(['M';'M';'F';'F';'F'],[38;43;38;40;49],...
    [71;69;64;67;64],[176;163;131;133;119])
T.Properties.VariableNames = {'data1' 'data2' 'data3' 'Weight'}

% Get variable names
var_names = T.Properties.VariableNames

% Get variable names that start with 'data' (filtering)
var_names_subset = var_names( strncmp( var_names, 'data', 4 ) )

% Index those variables only
T(:, var_names_subset)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A = rand(10,1);B=rand(10,1);data1=rand(10,1);data2=rand(10,1); %// data to fill the table
MyTable = table(A,B,data1,data2); %// create the table
VarNames = MyTable.Properties.VariableNames; %// get column names
DataCols = strfind(VarNames,'data'); %// find the cells containing 'data' in the name
kk=1; %// initialise counter
for ii = 1:numel(DataCols)
    if DataCols{ii}==1
        dataIdx(kk)=ii; %// if data exists, then store the index
        kk = kk+1;
    end
end
```

You can use [`MyTable.Properties.VariableNames`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tableproperties.html) to get a cell array of the variable names in your table. Then a [`strfind`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) finds all the cells which contain the phrase `'data'`. I then used a loop to check whether each cell contains a `1`, i.e. `'data'`, or not, though this might be done with [`cellfun`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) as well, but I am too unfamiliar with `cellfun` to get it to work.